# Expressjs check header on reloading page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

The authentication flow of Expressjs makes me confused.

I can set Auth/Token header from the ajax request, then Expressjs can find the header token and proceed with it, but how it works on page reload? Without any ajax request?

During reload the page, it`s just a get request for the HTML, and the javascript from the browser apparently cannot do anything here, but how Expressjs get the header that I want to set?

I want to set some custom token on the header, and every request post/get from express can extract it, just works like the basic authentication, once you enter the name/password, every request can be verified.

Can anyone explain that to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you should be able to send and receive headers on GET requests just as POST requests.

In express, extracting the header is the same regardless of the request type:

```
const tokenString = req.header('Authorization');
```

The standard practice is to use [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) on your routes to extract the token and authorize on every request.